# Only Allow ADT's with `case object`'s

Tags: scala

Given the Algebraic Data Type:

```
scala> sealed trait XYZ 
defined trait XYZ

scala> case object X extends XYZ
defined object X

scala> case class Y(name: String) extends XYZ
defined class Y
```

I'm trying to define a method:

`def f(a: ?): String`

that accepts an Algebraic Data Type, example: `XYZ`, but **only compiles** if all of its children are `case object`'s.

So, in the above example, I would expect `XYZ` to fail to compile.

How can I write this function using `compile-time` checks only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constrain to singletons:

```
scala> sealed trait T ; case object X extends T ; case class Y(y: String) extends T
defined trait T
defined object X
defined class Y

scala> def f[A <: Singleton](a: A) = a.toString
f: [A <: Singleton](a: A)String

scala> f(X)
res0: String = X

scala> f(Y("hi"))
<console>:15: error: inferred type arguments [Y] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [A <: Singleton]
       f(Y("hi"))
       ^
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Y
 required: A
       f(Y("hi"))
          ^
```

Sorry, you asked for this:

```
scala> sealed trait T { this: Singleton => } ; case object X extends T ; case class Y(y: String) extends T
<console>:11: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Y does not conform to T's selftype T with Singleton
       sealed trait T { this: Singleton => } ; case object X extends T ; case class Y(y: String) extends T
                                                                                                         ^
```

Comment: Where is `Singleton` defined? I can't find it anywhere in the API docs (including Predef), yet it works without importing anything...

Comment: @Dylan http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#singleton-types

Comment: This is just another indication how poor Scala documentation is.

Comment: TIL `Singleton` exists — never seen this before.

Comment: @SethTisue strictly speaking, singletons exist. I looked for mentions but failed. I'm pretty sure it's mentioned, though.